# sed to insert a string after matching pattern on a same line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I need to insert a command (as string) to an existing file after a certain match. The existing string is a long make command and I only need to modify it by inserting another string at specific location. I tried using sed but it either adds a new line before/after the matching string or replaces it. I'd like to know if at least it is possible to accomplish what I want with sed or should I be using something else? Could you please provide me with some hints?

Example:

The file contains two make commands and I am only interested in the second one without bbnote.

```
oe_runmake_call() {
        bbnote make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc" "$@"
        make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC="my_command_here arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"  --sysroot=/some/path "$@"

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:
http://hastebin.com/tigatoquje.go

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @danny what and where are you trying to add something?

Comment: I need to insert the string (command) into second make right after CC="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using **Sed**:

```
sed -r 's:(^\s+make.+ CC=\"):\1your_command_here :g' file.log >outfile.log
```

or with sed in-place edit:

```
sed -ir 's:(^\s+make.+ CC=\"):\1your_command_here :g' file.log
```

Without sed regex option:

```
sed 's:\(^\s\+make.\+ CC=\"\):\1your_command_here :g' file.log > outfile.log
```

Outputs:

```
oe_runmake_call() {
        bbnote make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc" "$@"
        make -j 8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC="your_command_here arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"  --sysroot=/some/path "$@"

}
```

How:

`sed -r 's:(^\s+make.+ CC=\"):\1your_command_here :g'`

`-r` = regex option

`^make(CC=\")` = starts with make and set a capture group on `CC="`

`\1your_command_here` = `\1` reference capture group then add command text

Comment: thanks for your response! I think it is what I was looking for. However, it complains about Unmatched ".
I removed the outside double quotes and replaced them with single as there is already one  that is being matched and not getting closed. It still doesn't work:(

Comment: make sure you are using the `-r` option

Comment: @danny try the "Without sed regex option" that I just added to my answer.

Comment: I tried: sed 's:\(^make.\+ CC=\"\):\1your_command_here :g' myfile > outfile.log but still nothing:(

Comment: Are you still getting the unmatched double quote error ? Also does your example file data match exactly to the file? As in are there maybe leading spaces or anything?

Comment: I no longer get unmatched double quote error. I think it has to do with the matching pattern. Sorry it does have some leading space but I thought that it would be ignored. Please take a look here: http://hastebin.com/tigatoquje.go

Comment: @danny thanks for input file, the whitespace in front makes a difference in the regex as the `^make` means starts with "make" however, your line starts with spaces so the regex is invalid. So the new regex (part) is `(^\s\+make.\+ `. Please check my answer for the latest update. I would recommend still using the "Without sed regex option". Also please update your question with the actual file contents.

Comment: Also you can read about the `^` regex (also known as an anchor) here: [regex anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl.

Replace `YOUR_COMMAND` with what you want added. This assumes your file is in `file.txt`:

```
perl -i.bak -pl -e '/^make/ and s/(CC=".*")/$1 YOUR_COMMAND /' file.txt
```